# Eclipse stopped auto complete in python

Tags: python, eclipse

I installed eclipse and used it a few times, shutting off and restarting it and everything seemed to working normally. This morning when I started working with it, it has stopped doing auto-complete and stopped initializing  the self key word. Also I had to reinstall the pydev packages this morning. Please any ideas??

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Did you set/reset the python interpreter? In eclipse its under Window->preferences->PyDev->Interpreter - Python. When setting up the interpreter usually you would just need to select Auto-Config, Apply, and OK should do it.

Comment: Oh, make sure the Windows Firewall is not blocking "Java(TM) Platform SE binary" it should be allowed to communicate over the "Home/Work (Private)" network. If it is not in the "Allowed programs and features" list under Windows -> Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Allowed Programs, you will have to manually add it and give it access.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something similar to this ["eclipse code completion issue"](http://linkapps.com/programming/19-python/41-pydev-with-eclipse-and-aptana-code-completion-freezes.html). Need to provide a bit more info though... Such as operating system in use, eclipse version, what packages are installed on eclipse? Any error dialogs showing up?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, I'm using windows 7 and I have eclipse Juno and I have pydev plugin installed